# How to get a location data from photos from iPhones?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, photos

I am having a trouble with extracting a location data from photos from iPhones by using `PHPhotoLibrary`. Can anyone teach me how?
Is it similar to how to do the same thing by using `ALAssetsLibrary`? Please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PHAsset location property`   to retrieve location data of image .
see [PHAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html)

Here is code:

```
  let CameraImages = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: nil)
    CameraImages.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({
        (obj, idx, bool) -> Void in
        var asset = obj  as! PHAsset

        let locationData = asset.location

    })
```

**EDIT**:
@Ryo comment: retrieve location data from the image that i choose from imagePickerController?

You can do as

```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    var arrayURL:[NSURL] = []
    var url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    arrayURL.append(url)
    let ImageAsset =  PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs(url1, options: nil)

    ImageAsset.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({
        (obj, idx, bool) -> Void in
        var asset = obj  as! PHAsset
        let locationData = asset.location
        print(locationData)

    })

}
```

**edit 2 :**
@ Ryo comment : how can i get a longitude and altitude from this location data?

just add this line

```
  if locationData != nil {
            let longi = locationData?.coordinate.longitude
            let lati = locationData?.coordinate.latitude
        }
```

Comment: now how can i retrieve location data from the image that i choose from imagePickerController? I mean,, how can i get a data from one specific image?

Comment: I just tried it but what i got from "print(locationData)" was nil. what should i do? Thnak you for answering my questions and helping me out!

Comment: check your image has GPS data or not. it is giving nil because your image does not have GPS data.

Comment: and it may be a silly question but how can i get a longitude and altitude from this location data? i want them separately.